# What is the appropriate way of handling user (action) related errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redux

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out the best way to handle errors from specific user actions. I'm using Express as my web server and even though it works, for the most part, I am getting not-so-useful, generic error messages. For instance, in the code below, I get the `Request failed with status code 400` error message on the client side for the first two conditions/exceptions in the try block.

How do I approach this in the following example?

**Express Server-side Controller**

```
async function voteInPoll (req, res) {
  const { category, pollId } = req.params;
  const { name, choiceId, voterId } = req.body;

  try {
    const poll = await Poll.findById(pollId);

    // Check if user has already voted in poll
    const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some(voter => voter.equals(voterId));

    if (!voterId) { // Check if user is authenticated
      res
        .sendStatus(400)
        .json({ message: 'Sorry, you must be logged in to vote' });
    } else if (voterId && hasVoted) {
      res
        .sendStatus(400)
        .json({ message: 'Sorry, you can only vote once' });
    } else {
      const choice = await poll.choices.id(choiceId);
      const votedChoice = { name, votes: choice.votes + 1 };

      await choice.set(votedChoice);
      await poll.votedBy.push(voterId);
      poll.save();

      res
        .sendStatus(200)
        .json({
          message: 'Thank you for voting. Find other polls at: ',
          poll,
        });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

**React/Redux Action**

```
export const voteInPoll = (category, pollId, votedItem, voterId) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:3050/polls/${category}/${pollId}/vote`,
      {
        ...votedItem, 
        voterId,
      }
    );

    dispatch({ type: store.polls.VOTE_SUCCESS, payload: response.data.poll });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({ type: store.polls.VOTE_FAILURE, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

**Edit**

What I find rather bizarre is I get the expected error response sent, as seen below under the Network tab of Chrome's Developer tools.
[image]

Comment: What does your clientside code look like? You'd need to specifically be looking for an error 400 and logging the error message, that won't happen automatically.

Comment: @jmcgriz I have updated my post to include the corresponding Redux action on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `res.sendStatus(statusCode)` because of the following as defined in the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus):

> Sets the response HTTP status code to statusCode and send its string representation as the response body.

The key thing about the above is:

> and send its string representation as the response body.

So doing: `res.sendStatus(400).json({ message: 'Oops 400!'})` will **not** give you a JSON response which is what you're expecting, but simply display:

```
Bad Request
```

Which is the *string representation* of the `400` HTTP status code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

What you need to do is replace all of your `res.sendStatus(..).json(..)` with `res.status(...).json(...)` like so:

```
if (!voterId) { // Check if user is authenticated
  res
    .status(400)
    .json({ message: 'Sorry, you must be logged in to vote' });
} else if (voterId && hasVoted) {
  res
    .status(400)
    .json({ message: 'Sorry, you can only vote once' });
} else {
  // ...
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had just that initially and still got the same results.